# How to specify server client id in google login with backend server

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

So I've followed the guide at:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

To add backend authentication with my javascript client for my API. However, using their code, at this line of code:

`idinfo = client.verify_id_token(token, CLIENT_ID)`

I'm getting an error on my server, and the error is this:

`Wrong recipient, <CLIENT_ID> != <SERVER_ID>`

How do I specify in my Javascript client what the server id is?

I have iOS and Android login working with this same backend code.

I has this same issue in iOS and was able to solve it by adding in the below code. Can I do the same in the browser?

`[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = @"SERVER_CLIENT_ID";`

Comment: did you set it at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#specify_your_apps_client_id ?

Comment: I've tried both the <meta> tag and the init() function approach

Comment: @rockwotjm Where did you find the server client id?

Comment: I created it, as the ID for my server in console.developer.Google.com I've since come up with a work around to sent the server's client ID to be the same as my web client ID. Although I feel like this is less ideal